# Is there a listener for a cursor being put into JTextField?

Tags: java, swing

Here is my application. It's a wallet to update my money when I spend or get profit. Look it up on image hosting here http://tinypic.com/r/687bdk/8

Is there a way to detect that a cursor has been put into one of the JTextFields? If there is, then could I dispatch a method that would delete whatever is in the other JTextField? There should only be one JTextField with input, it is unacceptable to have inputs in both text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to detect that a cursor has been put into one of the JTextfields? If there is, than I could dispatch a method that would delete whatever is in the other JTextField.

As a user I'm not too crazy about that design. I've used accounting type applications before where you have two columns (debit/credit) and a number can only be entered into one.

In those applications the number is not removed on focus, it is removed if a value is entered in the other field. This allows for tabbing between fields on the forum without data disappearing just because focus changes.

To implement this type of functionality you would add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the text field. Then whenever text is entered into the Document the listener is invoked and you can clear the text from the other text field.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `FocusListener` to each textfield i.e.

```
        JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();
        myTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                //when selected...
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                //when not selected..
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It called: `CaretListener`

```
jTextArea=new JTextArea();
jTextArea.addCaretListener(new CaretListener(){
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e){
      //your code
    }
  }
);
```

It mainly used when you need to know that your caret position is changed.